# How to approach to the Bessel function of second kind definition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

We know that we can find the Bessel function of first kind by using power series approach. My question is How to find the Bessel function of second kind?

Comment: With 'derive' you mean computing the derivative? There are lots of relations for the derivative of Bessel functions, see e.g. https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6

Comment: @gammatester no, that is "differentiate" in english. He probably means how to calculate some representation of the function.

Comment: Exactly @mathreadler . I want to know how to derive the expression for bessel function of second type.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it also using a power series approach.

Section 5.5 of *Advanced Engineering Mathematics 10th Edition* by Erwin Kreyszig walks you through the derivation.  You will need to read sections 5.3 and 5.4 to understand all the steps though.

A Google search for that title will show the book for sale by a number of online booksellers, and also a number of PDF copies available (probably errantly) online.